# custom datasource in spark-sql with mist

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql

I have custom data source which I use in `sqlContext.read.format(....sparkjobs.fileloader.DataSource)`. This works well via `spark-submit` in local & yarn mode.
But, when I invoke the same job via Mist, it throws exception:

```
Failed to find data source. Please find packages at http://spark-packages.org
```

My fat jar has the DataSource class. And also, at the beginning of the code, I logged all the jars available at classpath and I can see my jar.

Error Log:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Failed to find data source: c.p.b.f.sparkjobs.fileloader.DataSource. Pleas
e find packages at http://spark-packages.org

at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.ResolvedDataSource$.lookupDataSource(ResolvedDataSource.scala:77)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.ResolvedDataSource$.apply(ResolvedDataSource.scala:102)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:119)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:109)
        at c.p.b.f.sparkjobs.fileloader.m.McParser.processFile(McParser.scala:44)
        at c.p.b.f.sparkjobs.fileloader.FileProcessor$$anonfun$processFilesSingle$1.apply(FileProcessor.scala:7
3)
        at c.p.b.f.sparkjobs.fileloader.FileProcessor$$anonfun$processFilesSingle$1.apply(FileProcessor.scala:7
0)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)
        at scala.collection.IterableLike$class.foreach(IterableLike.scala:72)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:54)
        at c.p.b.f.sparkjobs.fileloader.FileProcessor.processFilesSingle(FileProcessor.scala:70)
        at c.p.b.f.sparkjobs.fileloader.FileProcessor$$anonfun$processFilesBulk$1.apply(FileProcessor.scala:58)
        at c.p.b.f.sparkjobs.fileloader.FileProcessor$$anonfun$processFilesBulk$1.apply(FileProcessor.scala:49)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)
        at scala.collection.MapLike$DefaultKeySet.foreach(MapLike.scala:174)
        at c.p.b.f.sparkjobs.fileloader.FileProcessor.processFilesBulk(FileProcessor.scala:49)
        at c.p.b.f.sparkjobs.fileloader.FileProcessor.init(FileProcessor.scala:33)
        at c.p.b.f.sparkjobs.fileloader.Loader.execute(Loader.scala:162)
        at c.p.b.f.util.LoaderApp$.execute(LoaderApp.scala:40)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at io.hydrosphere.mist.jobs.jar.JobInstance.io$hydrosphere$mist$jobs$jar$JobInstance$$invokeMethod(JobInstance.scala:40)
        at io.hydrosphere.mist.jobs.jar.JobInstance$$anonfun$run$1$$anonfun$apply$3$$anonfun$apply$4.apply(JobInstance.scala:24)
        at io.hydrosphere.mist.jobs.jar.JobInstance$$anonfun$run$1$$anonfun$apply$3$$anonfun$apply$4.apply(JobInstance.scala:24)
        at cats.syntax.CatchOnlyPartiallyApplied.apply(either.scala:294)
        at io.hydrosphere.mist.jobs.jar.JobInstance$$anonfun$run$1$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(JobInstance.scala:24)
        at io.hydrosphere.mist.jobs.jar.JobInstance$$anonfun$run$1$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(JobInstance.scala:23)
        at cats.syntax.EitherOps$.flatMap$extension(either.scala:129)
                at io.hydrosphere.mist.jobs.jar.JobInstance$$anonfun$run$1.apply(JobInstance.scala:23)
        at io.hydrosphere.mist.jobs.jar.JobInstance$$anonfun$run$1.apply(JobInstance.scala:22)
        at cats.syntax.EitherOps$.flatMap$extension(either.scala:129)
        at io.hydrosphere.mist.jobs.jar.JobInstance.run(JobInstance.scala:22)
        at io.hydrosphere.mist.worker.runners.scala.ScalaRunner$$anonfun$run$1.apply(ScalaRunner.scala:26)
        at io.hydrosphere.mist.worker.runners.scala.ScalaRunner$$anonfun$run$1.apply(ScalaRunner.scala:25)
        at cats.syntax.EitherOps$.flatMap$extension(either.scala:129)
        at io.hydrosphere.mist.worker.runners.scala.ScalaRunner.run(ScalaRunner.scala:25)
        at io.hydrosphere.mist.worker.runners.MistJobRunner$.run(MistJobRunner.scala:18)
        at io.hydrosphere.mist.worker.WorkerActor$$anonfun$2.apply(WorkerActor.scala:78)
        at io.hydrosphere.mist.worker.WorkerActor$$anonfun$2.apply(WorkerActor.scala:76)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:24)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:24)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: c.p.b.f.sparkjobs.fileloader.DataSource.DefaultSource
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.ResolvedDataSource$$anonfun$4$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(ResolvedDataSource.scala:62)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.ResolvedDataSource$$anonfun$4$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(ResolvedDataSource.scala:62)
        at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:161)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.ResolvedDataSource$$anonfun$4.apply(ResolvedDataSource.scala:62)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.ResolvedDataSource$$anonfun$4.apply(ResolvedDataSource.scala:62)
        at scala.util.Try.orElse(Try.scala:82)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.ResolvedDataSource$.lookupDataSource(ResolvedDataSource.scala:62)
        ... 47 more
```

Comment: can you post all the error log?

Comment: @ShankarKoirala added the error log. ResolvedDataSource class tries to load the provided custom datasource class and fails to find it. Am using spark-1.6.1 version